# Oracle Developer report, change field height

Tags: oraclereports

I am using oracle report 6i. I have a problem with the report design. I would like to change one of the field's height to be as high as another field. The second field does have not a fixed height, it depends on the data. So, I found Format Trigger, I have tried to get the height of the other field and set it to be in the current field, but I couldn't. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I know it is an old question, but nonetheless ...*

As far as I can tell, Format Trigger won't do any good here.

I'd go with creating a new frame that would contain both fields (how? Create it in Paper Layout Editor, paint it white (so that you can see what's going on), then move it "Back" until you see both fields appear "on top" of that frame, which means that they are contained in it). Make the frame *variable* vertically so that it could *grow* with field_1.

Another option you could try is to *anchor* field_2 to field_1.